# SFML loadFromFile undefined reference

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm learning to use SFML with the idea of making a small game, so far I've created a window and messed about with it's settings, and set up a draw loop and event handler.

The trouble started once I tried to add my first texture using the following code:

```
#include "SpaceNomad.ih"

void MainMenu(GameEngine &Engine)
{
    sf::Texture texture;

    if(!texture.loadFromFile("MenuBackGround.png"))
    {
        cout << "couldn't load background texture\n";
    }

    sf::Sprite *sprite = new sf::Sprite;
    sprite->setTexture(texture);

    Engine.AddEntity(sprite, 5);
}
```

which is outside of a different image literally the example code given on the [SFML tutorial page](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/graphics-sprite.php).

When I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in space nomad (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\projects\st\take2\MainMenu.o||In function     `Z8MainMenuR10GameEngine':|
D:\projects\st\take2\MainMenu.cpp|7|undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_4RectIiEE'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I have checked that all the sfml libraries are included in the build options(I'm using code::Blocks with GCC MinGW).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qzXcgqbLZtcHJWUy1vSUhpdVk/view?usp=sharing

Other topics I've seen deal with undefined references to functions people have made themselves, but here I'm using a library.

edit: I've just tried with the basic shape from the same libary:

```
    sf::CircleShape *shape = new sf::CircleShape(50);

    // set the shape color to green
    shape->setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 250, 50));

    Engine.AddEntity(shape, 5);
```

Which compiles and displays without a problem.

Comment: However, I have to add that even if you fix that undefined reference error, you'll face the `white square problem`. Also I don't think it's a good design to use the Heap whenever you can. Why is your `sf::Sprite`-Instance not on stack?

Comment: the idea was to keep the implementation of objects like the background or buttons and the draw loop seperate, where the draw loop only has a pointer to objects it needs to draw. Here the object implementation simply hasn't been implemented yet. If I had put it in the stack it would have been cleaned up by the time it would have been drawn.

Comment: Your texture gets cleaned up before drawn. A sprite has only a pointer to a texture, not a whole copy of the texture itself. Thus you'll encouter that the texture will not be drawn.

Comment: Did you link. besides `sfml-graphics`, `sfml-system`, too?

Comment: I added an image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4qzXcgqbLZtcHJWUy1vSUhpdVk/view where you can see how I linked sfml-audio-d, sfml-graphics-d, sfml-window-d, and sfml-system-d

Comment: and about the texture, I didn't know that but it's easely corrected thanks.

Comment: for windows you should add `sfml-main`, too. However, I'm sorry that I dont know what to do then. You might miss some inner-dependency SFML relies on. Consider recompiling SFML using CMake if you didn't already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using SFML libraries which were compiled with a different runtime or a different runtime ABI than you link your application against.

If your SFML libraries weren't compiled with the same compiler that you have, then you need to rebuild.

If you have set any special flags on your application (e.g. different ABI, C++14, etc.) you'll have to rebuild SFML with the same flags as well or remove them from your project.

Also it only happens sometimes because it doesn't affect the whole runtime libraries but parts like `std::string` which get used when calling the `loadFromFile` function.

Comment: Thanks, I used precompiled libraries before, tried to do a compile from sources which gave constant. leading me to install a new MinGW install recompiled with that which finally fixed the problem.

Comment: For people still struggling with this problem: I found out that SFML has to be compiled against `libjpeg-turbo`, **NOT** `libjpeg`. This is the reason why `loadFromFile` is failing. (If you use ArchLinux, you need to install `aur/mingw-w64-libjpeg-turbo` package and then to rebuild `aur/mingw-64-sfml`. Worked for me after struggling for hours!

Comment: That is **NOT** true. `libjpeg-turbo` and `libjpeg` share the same API, so you can obviously use either version. All you need to make sure that you use the 8.x API version and not the 9.x. And I highly doubt that you got the same errors as the OP, so your comment isn't even relevant here.