# SFML "undefined reference to `sf::Font::loadFromFile()' "

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm learning how to use SFML, and after completing the RenderWindow tutorial with no problems, I've begun trying to use `sf::Text` and `sf::Font` with the next tutorial on the page.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Font.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Text.hpp>

int main() {

    // initialise font
    sf::Font ubuntu_r;
    if(!ubuntu_r.loadFromFile("Ubuntu-R.ttf")) {
        // unable to load font
        std::cout << "Cannot load font." << std::endl;
    }

    // initialise text
    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(ubuntu_r);
    text.setString("Hello, world!");
    text.setCharacterSize(50);
    text.setColor(sf::Color(0x555555ff));

    // initialise window
    sf::RenderWindow win(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Hello, world!");

    // main loop
    while(win.isOpen()) {

        // check for closure
        sf::Event e;
        while(win.pollEvent(e)) {
            if(e.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                win.close();
            }
        }

        // draw text to screen
        win.clear(sf::Color::White);
        win.draw(text);
        win.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

resulting in the following on compile:

```
$ g++ -c text.cpp
$ g++ text.o -o text -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-window

text.o: In function `main':
text.cpp:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `sf::Font::loadFromFile(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is very confusing, as I've checked in `Font.hpp` and `loadFromFile()` is *definitely* defined.

Commenting out all the text and font related code results in a perfectly compiled program that creates a white window that closes normally.

Probably the weirdest thing of all, however, is that if I selectively comment just the `loadFromFile()` bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Font.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Text.hpp>

int main() {

    // initialise font
    sf::Font ubuntu_r;
    /*
    if(!ubuntu_r.loadFromFile("Ubuntu-R.ttf")) {
        // unable to load font
        std::cout << "Cannot load font." << std::endl;
    }
    */

    // initialise text
    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(ubuntu_r);
    text.setString("Hello, world!");
    text.setCharacterSize(50);
    text.setColor(sf::Color(0x555555ff));

    // initialise window
    sf::RenderWindow win(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Hello, world!");

    // main loop
    while(win.isOpen()) {

        // check for closure
        sf::Event e;
        while(win.pollEvent(e)) {
            if(e.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                win.close();
            }
        }

        // draw text to screen
        win.clear(sf::Color::White);
        //win.draw(text);
        win.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this program compiles, runs with a white screen as before, but gives a segfault on close!

```
$ g++ -c text.cpp
$ g++ text.o -o text -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics
$ ./text
```

(I click close on the window)

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What on earth is going on? Clearly the `sf::Font` isn't a problem as it compiles and runs fine with everything except `loadFromFile()`.

I'm unsure about the segfault, because on [this post](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=3591.0) the problems seem ever so slightly different to my own (it doesn't occur *every* time, for example). My initial thought is that the segfault is caused by the program trying to draw with an undefined font, but shouldn't that result in a runtime error as soon as the program is launched, and not only on closing the window?

Also, could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426810/sfml-loadfromfile-undefined-reference) be related to this problem? My error message looks pretty different.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, compiling with gcc in terminal and writing the code in jEdit.

Comment: If you're unable to load font, you should terminate the program immediately, instead of keep going which I guess causes the segmentation fault. { std::cout << "Cannot load font." << std::endl; **return 1;** }

Comment: That won't be the thing that causes the segmentation fault, as the segfault happens only when I remove that code entirely

Comment: Did you compile SFML yourself or are you using the precompiled libraries?

Comment: I used `sudo apt install libsfml-dev`, but I'm not sure if that uses my compiler or not...

Comment: It depends on the distro. Try compiling it the library from source.

Comment: Ah I did try doing that, but literally right at the end CMake refuses to cooperate... I'll try it though!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue: running Ubtunu, installed using that command, getting the same error on `font.loadFromFile` :/ just can't seem to find the solution

Comment: I'm afraid it really does look like you have to build SFML from source, which, sadly, on Linux, involves a lot of dependencies :(

Comment: For me, making the project link against `libc++` instead of `libstdc++` worked out: `cmake -B_build -H. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"`